# How to control the size of a textbutton inside listView in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using the following button snip:

```
  Widget _formTextButton(onPressed, buttonText) => TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Text(buttonText),
      );
```

I need to be able to control the size of the button, is there any way to do that?
I tried to put it inside a SizedBox but I could not get it to work!

Comment: Using the padding property isn't enough?

Comment: can you add your parent widget? the code fine in sizedbox.

Comment: listview is the parent widget

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  Widget _formTextButton(onPressed, buttonText) => ConstrainedBox(
  constraints:BoxConstraints(
    minHeight:80, // change it to what you need
    minWidth:200, // change it to what you need
    ),
    child: TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Text(buttonText),
      )
);
```

this will force the widget to be at minimal in that height and width

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for set `width` for `TextButton` in `listView` is use `Align` and `SizedBox` like this:

```
Widget _formTextButton(onPressed, buttonText) => Align(
  child: SizedBox(
     width: 40,
     height: 20,
     child: TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Text(buttonText),
      )
   )
);
```

[image]

Comment: @JuanCasas was it what you want?